# How to properly close a HTTP connection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http

I've been looking for a proper way to close a HTTP connection and have found nothing yet.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/")


http.start
resp = http.request request

p resp.body
```

So far so good, but now when I try to close the connection guessing which method to use:

```
http.shutdown   # error
http.close      # error
```

when I check `ri Net::HTTP.start`, the documentation explicitly says

> the caller is responsible for closing it (the connection) upon completion

I don't want to use the block form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method to close the connection is `http.finish`.

The `net/http` API is particularly confusing to use. It is generally easier to use a higher-level library instead, such as [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [REST Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client), which will provide a more intuitive API and take care of the lower level details for you.

Answer (score 2):

> If the optional block is given, the newly created Net::HTTP object is passed to it and closed when the block finishes.

[from ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-start)

Comment: Hello ck3g, thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use the block form (for some reasons).